# How build app from x64?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

I create application in visual studio 2010. 
I tested on server 2003 r2  x64 and the program does not start.
trying to compile x64 and I crash exception

> Error while Trying to run Project:
>   Debugger cannot start: The assembly to
>   be debugged  was built with platform
>   incompatible with the current system

Comment: Is this any use for you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfx64bit/thread/3e280612-f63f-4611-937f-64eafd25457d

Comment: Did you find a solution on this? If so, please share and mark your own question as the answer. :) This could be of help to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application references 32-bit .dll-files it can't run as 64-bit. Either .Net assemblies compiled to x86-target (which is default now), or P/Invoke on native Windows .dll-files, will prevent you from running your 64-bit app.

The Windows installation you are running this on also needs to be 64-bit in order for it to handle 64-bit debugging. (Note: Compiling to 64-bit will work fine!)

Set target CPU type to x86 in project properties (under Build) to make it work. If you don't reference any external 32-bit .dll's you can set it to "any" to let .Net decide. It will then run 64-bit mode on 64-bit operating systems and 32-bit mode on 32-bit operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about VS2010, but for VS2005 I build with "Mixed Platforms" set for "Active solution platform."